# Trying to convert a column of strings to float

Tags: python, arrays, python-3.x, pandas

I have a column in a dataframe that is currently strings. I need to convert this data into floats and extract as an array so that I can use the coordinate pairs.

```
In [55]:apt_data['geotag']

Out[55]:

 0        (40.7763, -73.9529)
 1     (40.72785, -73.983307)
 2        (40.7339, -74.0054)
 3    (40.771731, -73.956313)
 4      (40.8027, -73.949187)
Name: geotag, dtype: object'
```

First I tried:

```
apt_loc = apt_data['geotag']
apt_loc_ar = np.array(apt_loc['geotag'], dtype=dt)
```

But that threw this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):

File "<ipython-input-60-3a853e355c9a>", line 1, in <module>
apt_loc_ar = np.array(apt_loc['geotag'], dtype=dt)

File "/python3.5/site-
packages/pandas/core/series.py", line 603, in __getitem__
result = self.index.get_value(self, key)

File "/python3.5/site-
packages/pandas/indexes/base.py", line 2169, in get_value
tz=getattr(series.dtype, 'tz', None))

File "pandas/index.pyx", line 98, in pandas.index.IndexEngine.get_value 
(pandas/index.c:3557)

File "pandas/index.pyx", line 106, in pandas.index.IndexEngine.get_value 
(pandas/index.c:3240)

File "pandas/index.pyx", line 156, in pandas.index.IndexEngine.get_loc 
(pandas/index.c:4363)

KeyError: 'geotag'
```

I've tried to use 
`apt_data['geotag'] = pd.to_numeric(apt_data['geotag'], errors='coerce')`

This gives me NaN for all entries.

Thanks.

Comment: so each observation is a tuple inside a string?

Comment: `type(apt_loc.get_value(0,'geotag')` yields `str`. I think that the parentheses and comma are just string values too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `literal_eval` from `ast` module and apply a function to your DataFrame, like below:

```
import pandas as pd
from ast import literal_eval as le

df = pd.DataFrame(["(40.7763, -73.9529)","(40.72785, -73.983307)"], columns=["geotag"])

df["geotag"] = df["geotag"].apply(func=lambda x: le(x))
```

Output:

```
>>> for k in df["geotag"]:
        for j in k: print(type(j))
<class 'float'>
<class 'float'>
<class 'float'>
<class 'float'>
```

Comment: Welcome. And don't hesitate to leave your comments if you have any. Happy coding.

Answer (score 1):

Shorter version of Chiheb's answer (no import needed) :

```
apt_data.geotag.apply(eval)
```

Comment: `eval` isn't secure and it's not recommended to use it.

Answer (score 1):

Consider the series `g`

```
g = pd.Series(
    [
        '(40.7763, -73.9529)',
        '(40.72785, -73.983307)',
        '(40.7339, -74.0054)',
        '(40.771731, -73.956313)',
        '(40.8027, -73.949187)'
    ], name='geotag'
)
```

**Option 1**
*`literal_eval`*

```
from ast import literal_eval
import pandas as pd

g.apply(literal_eval)

0        (40.7763, -73.9529)
1     (40.72785, -73.983307)
2        (40.7339, -74.0054)
3    (40.771731, -73.956313)
4      (40.8027, -73.949187)
Name: geotag, dtype: object
```

**Option 2**
*`literal_eval` in a comprehension and reconstruct*

```
pd.Series([literal_eval(v) for v in g.values.tolist()], g.index, name=g.name)

0        (40.7763, -73.9529)
1     (40.72785, -73.983307)
2        (40.7339, -74.0054)
3    (40.771731, -73.956313)
4      (40.8027, -73.949187)
Name: geotag, dtype: object
```

**Option 3**
*`apply` with `str` functions*

```
g.apply(lambda x: [float(y) for y in x.strip('()').split(', ')])

0        [40.7763, -73.9529]
1     [40.72785, -73.983307]
2        [40.7339, -74.0054]
3    [40.771731, -73.956313]
4      [40.8027, -73.949187]
Name: geotag, dtype: object
```

**Option 4**
*`str` functions in a comprehension*

```
pd.Series([[float(x) for x in v.strip('()').split(', ')] for v in g.values.tolist()], g.index, name=g.name)

0        [40.7763, -73.9529]
1     [40.72785, -73.983307]
2        [40.7339, -74.0054]
3    [40.771731, -73.956313]
4      [40.8027, -73.949187]
Name: geotag, dtype: object
```

---

**Timing**

```
%timeit g.apply(literal_eval)
10000 loops, best of 3: 158 µs per loop

%timeit g.apply(lambda x: [float(y) for y in x.strip('()').split(', ')])
10000 loops, best of 3: 107 µs per loop

%timeit pd.Series([literal_eval(v) for v in g.values.tolist()], g.index, name=g.name)
10000 loops, best of 3: 119 µs per loop

%timeit pd.Series([[float(x) for x in v.strip('()').split(', ')] for v in g.values.tolist()], g.index, name=g.name)
10000 loops, best of 3: 65.3 µs per loop
```

Comment: I really enjoy reading your answers. You may write a book about Python/Pandas. :-). You deserve an upvote fors this answer.

Comment: Thank you for the kind comments @ChihebNexus